# Fuzzy Group - Match using OR operator

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, ssis, fuzzy-logic, fuzzy-comparison

Please see the screenshot below:

[image]

The records will be grouped if the following fields match:

Surname AND Forename AND DateOfBirth AND pncid

Is it possible to configure the Fuzzy group to match based on:

(Surname AND Forename AND DateOfBirth) OR pncid

Do I have to create two fuzzy groups and merge them i.e. one for

```
Surname AND Forename AND DateOfBirth AND pncid
```

and the other for: `PNCID`